pg_restore through .bat on pgAdmin4
I am reaching out to seek assistance with an issue I've encountered while transitioning from PostgreSQL 9.4 to PostgreSQL 16. The primary reason for this upgrade was the discontinuation of PostGIS support in version 9.4. Although the database was previously hosted on pgAdmin III, I am now attempting to restore it on pgAdmin4. Despite receiving an exit code 0, which typically indicates a successful operation, the table restoration process does not seem to be executing as expected.
I have followed the standard procedures for database restoration, yet the issue persists. I suspect there might be compatibility issues or additional steps required when migrating between these specific versions of PostgreSQL and pgAdmin.
I've encountered an issue while attempting to restore a database using a .batch file in pgAdmin, which previously worked without any problems in pgAdmin III. The process now exits with code 0, indicating an unsuccessful restore.
cd/D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_POLYGONS% 2>%FE_POLYGONS_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %SURVEYSTATUS% 2>%SURVEY_STATUS_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE2_METER_MITIGATION_DATA% 2>%FE2_METER_MITIGATION_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_NETWORK_DATA% 2>%FE_NETWORK_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE2_METER% 2>%FE2_METER_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_STYLES_DATA% 2>%FE_STYLES_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_NODE_DATA% 2>%FE_NODE_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE2_METER_HISTORICAL_DATA% 2>%FE2_METER_HISTORICAL_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_METER_DEMAND_DATA% 2>%FE_METER_DEMAND_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %FE_METER_IN_OR_OUT_DATA% 2>%FE_METER_IN_OR_OUT_DATA_LOG% 
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %RE_INSTALL_DATA% 2>%RE_INSTALL_DATA_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %RE_PERFORMANCE_DATA% 2>%RE_PERFORMANCE_DATA_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %CGR_INSTALL_DATA% 2>%CGR_INSTALL_DATA_LOG%
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w --dbname FE_SMI_NJ --verbose %CGR_PERFORMANCE_DATA% 2>%CGR_PERFORMANCE_DATA_LOG%

this is in the LOG pg_restore:

error: could not open input file "C:\NEW_JERSEY\POD\BACKUPS_NJ\fe_polygons_.backup": No such file or directory


It looks as if the batchfile either is not complete or is called by another script or you have to setup a lot of OS environment variables manually. Such as FE_POLYGONS, FE_POLYGONS_LOG and so on. Both in my example should be filenames where the first (contained in FE_POLYGONS) has to exist, while the second (contained in FE_POLYGONS_LOG does not - at least not before the script runs the first time.
What error logs do you have in the log files that are specified by the  ..._LOG environment variables?

i just posted a bit of the script...set backup_local_dir=C:\NEW_JERSEY\POD\BACKUPS_NJ
echo backup directory path is %backup_local_dir%
set FE_POLYGONS="%backup_local_dir%fe_polygons_%datestr%.backup"
set FE_POLYGONS_LOG="%backup_local_dir%Log_FE_Polygons_Restore_%datestr%.txt"

echo fe_polygons file name is %FE_POLYGONS%

And this is in the LOG pg_restore: error: could not open input file "C:\NEW_JERSEY\POD\BACKUPS_NJ\fe_polygons_.backup": No such file or directory

does the file from the error log actually exist? (Then you have a problem with permissions) If it doesn't, you have to set the correct path to the actual backup files. Or do other files from the backup exist in the folder where the current batch script expects the .backup file?
